# Bullets (ul) changing place while code's the same

Tags: html, css

I insert a `<ul>` in my simple html-page and it behaves really strange.
Here you can see bullets are OK:
[image: Normal]

But after several refreshes (**with no changes in code**) it starts looking like this
[image: not normal]

If I refresh the page several times again, it will look OK again. And it goes on and on.

Here's HTML for this:

```
            <div class="image-paragraph">
            <img class="image-left" src="image/nozh_fmt.jpg" alt="knife" />
                    <img class="image-left" src="image/perchatki_fmt.jpg" alt="gloves" />
                <p class="Text-main">

                    <ul>
                        <li>Яхтенные перчатки (лучше приобрести специальные).</li>
                        <li>Солнцезащитные очки на веревочке.</li>
                        <li>Боцманский нож, фонарик с запасными батарейками.</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
```

And here are the styles:

```
div.image-paragraph {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
img.image-left, svg.image-left{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    max-width: 30%;
}
.image-left:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
p.Text-main {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 0px;
}
```

What it can be about??

Comment: add overflow:hidden to <p> and look for about clearing float :) to understand the use of it

Comment: Do you mind showing how you load your css?

Comment: it's all about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context when dealing with float :)

Comment: In most browsers, you can right click on an element and select Inspect Element (or something similar). That will show you your HTML and the CSS applied to it. Just a debugging tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are dealing with `float`, you need to mind the [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) wich tells how containers or sibblings to float elements behave , in other words: *does it see float and wrap them or around or not at all ?*

If you follow the link, then `overflow` is the easiest to apply.

```css
div.image-paragraph {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

img.image-left,
svg.image-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.image-left:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

div.Text-main {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid;/* see me */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-paragraph">
  <img class="image-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/80x80" alt="knife" />
  <img class="image-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/80x80" alt="gloves" />
  <div class="Text-main">
    <ul>
      <li>Яхтенные перчатки (лучше приобрести специальные).</li>
      <li>Солнцезащитные очки на веревочке.</li>
      <li>Боцманский нож, фонарик с запасными батарейками.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code with a border on `.Textmain`

```css
div.image-paragraph {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

img.image-left,
svg.image-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.image-left:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

div.Text-main {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 0px;
  border:solid;/* see me */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-paragraph">
  <img class="image-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/80x80" alt="knife" />
  <img class="image-left" src="http://dummyimage.com/80x80" alt="gloves" />
  <div class="Text-main">
    <ul>
      <li>Яхтенные перчатки (лучше приобрести специальные).</li>
      <li>Солнцезащитные очки на веревочке.</li>
      <li>Боцманский нож, фонарик с запасными батарейками.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**: `<p>` can only hold phrasing content, you should use a `<div>` here

Comment: Yep, that worked! (Since you left a comment) Xtra thanks for link and note!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try using `ul {overflow: hidden;}`

Here's a jsFiddle with your code, I simply added that line: https://jsfiddle.net/sm3zb6ca/

To further note, using `ul {overflow: auto;}` would work

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

More about visual formatting can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting